# Cognos Report Studio: How can I change the image displayed based on a query output?

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-bi

Using Cognos Report Studio:

I have a query that returns two numbers, and based on those two numbers I need to display an up, down or straight arrow. Images stored in the server.

Here are my conditions:

```
If (num1 > num2) then (green arrow)
If (num1 < num2) then (red arrow)
If (num1 = num2) then (straight arrow)
```

I've tried using a `string` variable called `vImage` with the following condition:

```
case
   when (num1 > num2) then (GreenArrow.png)
   when (num1 < num2) then (RedArrow.png)
   when (num1 > num2) then (StraightArrow.png)
end
```

With `num1` and `num2` as query results.
Those `.png` files are my list of answers.

On my report, I have the `Image` layout element with the `URL Source Variable` set to that `Image` variable.

When I Run HTML though, the report element returns blank.

I have tried selecting and un-selecting values in the URL source variable dialog, but nothing seems to be working.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you heard about report variables and conditional blocks?

Comment: Please provide a sample report spec using the samples data.  This helps identify the specific problem and ensures you have done the leg work so we answer the question with the least effort on our part.

Comment: If the spec is too big to post here, there are other services (pastebin.com, for example) that you can link to from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the requirement is just up and down arrow I really would not bother with images at all.  Simply copy the ascii arrow into the if clause.  https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrow-symbols/#up-arrows.  Once completed, use the conditional style to adjust the font color.

```
case
   when (num1 > num2) then (▲)
   when (num1 < num2) then (▲)
   when (num1 > num2) then (▲)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a variable.

For your image column:
Set the URL Source | Source Type property to *Report expression*.
Set the expression to something like this:

```
'/Graphics/' + 
case
    when [Query1].[num1] > [Query1].[num2]
        then 'Green'
    when [Query1].[num1] < [Query1].[num2]
        then 'Red'
    else 'Straight'
end
 + 'Arrow.png'
```

Adjust to accommodate the actual path to your images.
You'll also need to consider the effects of how you craft your URL on the output format.  HTML image URLs are evaluated by the client browser.  Image URLs in Excel or PDF output are evaluated by the Cognos service.  Images may appear in one output format and not another.